# How do I retrieve a Stripe Paymentintent id from a Checkout Session?

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe used to return a Paymentintent id when a checkout session was created.

However, since the 2022-11-15 API update, this is no longer the case.

Instead a new event "A request to confirm a Checkout Session completed" returns the Paymentintent id.

Is there any way I could access the Paymentintent id using the original checkout session event?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is an expected change that was introduced in API version `2022-08-01` [source](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-08-01:%7E:text=A%20PaymentIntent%20is%20no%20longer%20created%20during%20Checkout%20Session%20creation%20in%20payment%20mode.%20Instead%2C%20a%20PaymentIntent%20will%20be%20created%20when%20the%20Session%20is%20confirmed.).

Checkout Sessions no longer create a Payment Intent when they are created, instead they create it when they are confirmed, so it is not possible to get the ID of the associated Payment Intent from the Checkout Session creation request's response, as no associated Payment Intent has been created at that point.